# Prove that this limit equals to 2.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Prove $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{1-\cos(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})}=2$$

Comment: Let $r = \sqrt{x^2+ y^2}$, then the function only depends on $r$, and you can evaluate the limit as a limit in one variable.

Comment: Rationalise the denominator and proceed as ordinary limits one at a time

Answer (score 2):

You can use polar coordinates, that is,
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
x = r \cos(\theta) \\
y = r \sin(\theta)
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

so the statement $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ is equivalent to $r \rightarrow 0$ (whatever path you choose, it is determined also by the angle, which you don't fix). Then this limit becomes

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(r^2)}{1-\cos(r)}
\end{equation*}

and now you can use, for example, l'Hôpital, or the Taylor expressions
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\sin(x) = x + O(x^3) \\
\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + O(x^4)
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

(with this orders you will get enough).

Comment: Or just multiply numerator and denominator by $r^2$ splitting the fraction as $\frac{\sin(r^2)}{r^2}\frac{r^2}{1-\cos r}$.

Comment: What about that?

Comment: The two final fractions have known limits, don't they?

Comment: Yes, that's true, but the reason is the above Taylor expansions, so I think it is instructive to clarify it in here.